Incorrect C++ code formatting of pointer near char using listings package and lstlistings
I try to do simple hello world of C++ in LaTeX with listings package. Better one time to see.

Here the code:
\begin{figure}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language={[11]C++},
      %float,
      keepspaces=true,
      escapeinside={},
      showspaces=false,
      showstringspaces=false,
      stringstyle=\color{green},
      frame=single,
      numbers=left]
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return std::cout.fail();
}   \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{C++ Hello World Example}
    \label{lst:hello}
\end{figure}

On the image you can see strange position near char** they look like underscore but why and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Welcome on TeX StackExchange!

You should always provide a full compilable file (that is to say with the \documentclass, the \begin{document},) etc.

I suggest you to try the package piton (it requires the use of LuaLuaTeX).
Here your example formatted by piton with the font JetBrains Mono.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{piton}

\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}

\begin{document}

\SetPitonStyle[C]{String.Long = \color{green}}

\begin{Piton}[language = C,line-numbers]
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return std::cout.fail();
}
\end{Piton}

\end{document}



Thanks for \setmonofont{JetBrains Mono} now it works!

As I find out problem with font. I use JetBrains Mono font. If I change font with code:
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
all looks nice, but now I need to find out how to use JetBrains Mono inside code listings...
How it looks:

Update: fix for JetBrains Mono font was simple I just set in only
like this: \setmainfont{JetBrains Mono}
and need to add: \setmonofont{JetBrains Mono} now all looks nice:


Please also provde a compilable code example in the answers you post to make it easy for others to understand what is going on.
